# Style and Show command Link as Command Button in Classic & Lightning

Tags: lightning-design-system, slds, commandbutton, salesforce-classic, commandlink

I would like a command link to look like a command button. I was once told that I could to that with using the style.

Comment: You should probably describe this better - are you using this in Visualforce?

Answer (score 2):

**For Lightning** you can use following styleClass attribute:

> styleClass="slds-m-top_xx-small slds-button slds-button_neutral
>   btnSubmit"

i.e.,

```
<apex:commandLink 
    target="_top" 
    styleClass="slds-m-top_xx-small slds-button slds-button_neutral btnSubmit" 
    style="margin:0 auto;" 
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Acount.View, $CurrentPage.Parameters.Id)}" 
    value="Back"/>
```

**For Classic** you can use following styleClass attribute:

> styleClass="btn"

i.e.,

```
<apex:commandLink 
    target="_top" 
    styleClass="btn" 
    style="margin:0 auto;" 
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, $CurrentPage.Parameters.Id)}" 
    value="Back"/>
```